# Create.js.erb Javascript asking for partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get my my create action to work in my rails app. When I have these two lines

```
$('#pit_form').remove(); //remove form
$('#new_link').show();  //show new link again
```

it functions properly, and removes the form plus adds the link back, but I can't show the new pit with my escape. I've tried a few things but it always gives me this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial pits/_pit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/markhustad/projects/fire_2/app/views"
  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views"
):
    1: $('#pit_form').remove(); //remove form
    2: $('#new_link').show();  //show new link again
    3: $('#pit_index').append(<%= j (render(@pit)) %>);
  app/views/pits/create.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_pits_create_js_erb___3365989432298988625_2214355520'
  app/controllers/pits_controller.rb:20:in `create'
```

when I add this line or something similar(not sure why I need _pit partial)

```
$('#pit_index').append(<%= j (render(@pit)) %>);
```

My pits controller currently

```
class PitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :current_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

def new
  @pit = Pit.new
end

def index
  @pit = Pit.all
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  @pits = Pit.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').group_by { |pit| pit.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
end




def create
  @pit = current_user.pits.create(pit_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to pits_path}
        format.js
  end
end



def show
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
end

def update
   @pit = Pit.find(pit_params[:id])
     if @pit.update_attributes(pit_params)
       redirect_to @pit
     end
end

def destroy
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:id])
  @pit.destroy
end


def upvote
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @pit.upvote_from current_user
  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end

def downvote
  @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
  @pit.downvote_from current_user
  redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
end


private

def correct_user
    @pit = current_user.pits.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_path if @pit.nil?
  end

def pit_params
    params.require(:pit).permit(:topic, :summary, :image, :video_url, :author, :user_id)
end

end
```

Pits index

```
<div class = "container list-pits"> 
  <%= link_to "Add New Pit", new_pit_path, id: "new_link", remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <% @pit.each do |pit| %>

  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "well", id = "pit_index"> 
       <h3 id="pit-title"><%= link_to pit.topic, pit_path(pit) %></h3>
       <p>by <%= link_to pit.author, '#' %></p>
          <br>
            <p><%= pit.summary %></p>
            <p>Replies (<%= pit.comments.count %>)</p>
          <br>

            <p>Pit Created by: <%= link_to pit.user.name, pit.user %> on <%= pit.created_at %></p>

            <%= link_to "View Pit", pit_path(pit), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <%= link_to "Delete Pit", pit_path(pit), remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>
      </div>
    </div>
      <% end %>


 </div>
```

_form in Pits

```
<div class="container new-pit">

<%= render 'devise/shared/error_messages', obj: @pit %>

<%= form_for @pit, remote: true, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

   <div class = "form-horizontal", id = "pit_form">

      <div class="form-group">
                   <%= f.label :topic, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <%= f.text_field :topic, class: "form-control", autofocus: true %>
             </div>  
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
                   <%= f.label :author, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <%= f.text_field :author, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Enter name of book author, lecturer, or presenter" %>
             </div>  
      </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                   <%= f.label :summary, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <%= f.text_area :summary, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Present an argument for or against the material presented and state why you think it is accurate or not" %>
             </div>  
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                   <%= f.label :image, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
             </div>  
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                   <%= f.label :video, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <%= f.text_field :video_url, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "example: //www.youtube.com/embed/hBHYdK9xtYs (video is optional)" %>
                   <p class = "youtube-instruction">Must use the shared -> embed option</p>
             </div>  
           </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                      <%= f.submit "Start Pit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
               </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>



<% end %>
```

I know I'm close here but need a bit more direction. Thanks.

Comment: when you say: `<%= j (render(@pit)) %>` it will look for a partial _pit.html.erb inside pits(because it is the controller's name directory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried a few things. I just want it to add the new pit then show the pit page with that new pit.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things. First, a `pit.js.erb` file that has:

```
$('#pit_form').remove();
$('#new_link').show();
$('#pit_index').append(<%= j (render(@pit)) %>);
```

I think you already have this.

You also need a `_pit.html.erb` file under the `/pits` folder that describes the layout of individual pit items on the pit index.

The order of operations goes like this:

1. Send a create request via Ajax. On forms, this is typically done with the `remote: true` option, which uses Unobstrusive JavaScript.
2. Process the response in the controller's `create` action using `format.js`. By default, this renders the .js.erb file that corresponds to the action name (i.e. `create.js.erb`).
3. Inside this js.erb file, you can also embed more render commands. In your specific case, you are trying to render a `_pit.html.erb` or a `_pit.js.erb` template, both of which are missing.

If you already have the `pit` template in a specific folder, you can specify it in the render action, like this:

```
$('#pit_index').append("<%= j (render 'myfolder/pit') %>");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ege. I'll see what works here.

Comment: I ended up doing this

$('#pit_form').remove(); //remove form
$('#new_link').show();  //show new link again
$('#pit_index').append("<%= j (render :partial => 'pits/pit', :collection => @pits) %>") which apparently works but does not load the content. It just gives me a blank space. I even defined @pits within the create controller. My logs, however, say its loading.

Comment: What do you mean by "apparently works but does not load the content"? If you are not getting any errors, check the DOM to see if the markup actually loads. You can also try this: `<%= j (render 'myfolder/pit', pit: @pit) %>`

Comment: I probably should have been clearer. I meant that the it is appearing to work in that my logs show it loading and rendering.

Comment: Not sure whats up. I tried your suggestion and it seems I need to use the collection method as that seems to be the only thing that prevents an error. I'm, still however not getting the form to actually load. It loads my link and then some white space and then the rest of the page. Thanks for you help BTW. Much appreciated.